# how to make it 100% width and height in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

well earlier i asked for a script which can load game which showing some banner until the game is loading and the load progress that it shows, it shouldn't be fake, many people said you need flash for it, but atlast i found a script that can do that for me.
BUT there is a issue when i started using the script in the script the width and height can be in px like width 500 but it can't be made to width 100% when i make it 100% the script stops working.
I can't use px or any other thing except 100% as i want the flash to increase its width and height with the change in screen resolution.

Here is the script, you can make a demo html file out of it for testing purposes, if you don't want to make one i am ready to provide a demo page too, please leave a comment for it. Thank you ^_^

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Pre-roll Example page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.cryoffalcon.com/woro/preroll.dev.js"></script>
    <style>
        .gamecontent                {width:923px;padding:0px;margin:0px auto 0px auto;background-color:#FFF;}
        .gamecontent .gamewrapper   {margin:0px auto 0px auto;}
        .gamecontent .game          {float:left;margin:0px auto 0px auto;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;width:1px;height:1px}
        .gamecontent .ad            {display:none;width:300px;height:300px;margin:0px auto 0px auto;padding:50px auto 0px auto;text-align:center;font-size:10px}
        .gamecontent .ad #progress  {width:200px;height:10px;margin:10px auto 0px auto;padding:0px;border:solid 1px #E7B9D1;text-align:left;}
        .gamecontent .ad #pbar      {width:0px;height:10px;background-color:#CCC;}
        .gamecontent .ad #pskip     {text-align:center;}    
        .medrectangle               {width:300px;height:250px;border:none}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="gamecontent">
    <div class="gamewrapper" style="height:640px;width:640px;">
      <div class="game" id="gameframe"></div>
        <div id="adframe" class="ad">
            <div>Advertisement</div>
            <div id="plad"></div>
            <div id="progress"></div>
        </div>
        <noscript>  
            <div>
                 <!--Game embed code should be placed here here-->
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var af = 'adframe';
var gf = 'gameframe';
var gid = 'gameswf';
var adinvoke = '<iframe class="medrectangle" src="<!--to show my logo or ad-->" scrolling="no"></iframe>';

function skipad() {
    $('#plad').html('<div></div>');
    $('#'+af).hide();
    $('#'+gf).css('width','640px');
    $('#'+gf).css('height','640px');
}
$('#gameframe').preloadad(
    {  // calls the init method
      swf       : 'http://games.balloontowerdefense.net/b/balloon_tower_defense_4_expansion.swf',
      width     : 640,
      height    : 640,
      gameid    : gid,
      gameframe : gf,
      adframe   : af,
      adcode    : adinvoke,
      pltime    : 10000,
      gametype  : 'swf',
      base      :'http://games.balloontowerdefense.net/b/',
      skiptxt   : 'Click here to show the game',
      showad    :'1'
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

in the above code the 640 width and height is the issue, as it doesn't work with 100% values, i was wondering how to make it work with 100% width and height. I don't know what did i miss or where did i go wrong?

Comment: can you try width:auto;height:auto;

Comment: sorry brother but auto is not working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using this plugin: http://www.balloontowerdefense.net/jquery-preloader/jquery-preloader.html, there are two ways I can see going about this.

First (the more flexible of the two):

Modify the plugin to use user-supplied units instead of pixels. To do this, you will need to modify two functions in the plugin, `applygameiframe` and `showgame`.

`applygameiframe` should be changed to:

```
var applygameiframe = function() {
  var gc = '#'+settings.gameframe;
  var iframe = $('<iframe />').attr({
    "id": settings.gameid,
    "src": settings.swf,
    "frameborder": 0,
    "scrolling": "no",
    "marginwidth": 0,
    "marginheight": 0
  }).css({
    "height":'settings.height
    "width": settings.width
  });
  $(gc).append(iframe);
  return true;
};
```

`showgame` should be changed to:

```
var showgame = function() {
    var ac   = '#' + settings.adframe;
    var game = '#' + settings.gameframe;
    $(ac).hide();
    $(game).css({
    "width": settings.width,
    "height": settings.height
    });
};
```

Once those changes are made, the inline CSS should be set to whatever you supply as parameters (i.e., `100%`, `50em`, etc.).

The second way (and less flexible) is to grab the window size (or the calculated height/width, whichever you're going for) and sub that in for the height/width:

```
$('#gameframe').preloadad({ // calls the init method
    swf: 'http://games.balloontowerdefense.net/b/balloon_tower_defense_4_expansion.swf',
    width: window.screen.availWidth, // or $('div.gamewrapper')[0].clientWidth
    height: window.screen.availHeight, // or $('div.gamewrapper')[0].clientHeight
    gameid: gid,
    gameframe: gf,
    adframe: af,
    adcode: adinvoke,
    pltime: 10000,
    gametype: 'swf',
    base: 'http://games.balloontowerdefense.net/b/',
    skiptxt: 'Click here to show the game',
    showad: '1'
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for a quick reply. Well i used your first method and changed the plugin, here is how it looks like after applying the changes that you recommended http://files.cryoffalcon.com/Piecemaker/preroll.dev.js but it didn't worked. It still stops working when i add values 100% to this part of the above script, here you can see i changed all values of 640 to 100% and did the plugin change but still not working . NOW IT DOESN'T WORK EVEN WITH PIXEL VALUES.
Can you tell me where did i go wrong? here is the link to image of the changed script http://screencast.com/t/GTemcaKqE3Ye

Comment: i didn't try your 2nd method as i like your first one ^_^

Comment: I tried your 2nd method too, with both codes that you provided, it doesn't work, it makes the width fixed, its not elastic anymore plus it creates a weird effect. So as you mentioned 2nd method is not very flexible, but i don't know why is the first one not working?